# ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

**Buenos días resulta que tengo que hacer lo siguiente :** Hacer una funcion que reciba el numero de una factura y devuelva el importe de esta.

**Y al ejecutar la funcion me devuelve el siguiente mensaje :** ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row (MySQL)

**Os dejo un enlace de mis tablas :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/58

## Tabla articulos

```
CREATE TABLE articulos(
    cod_art VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(45),
    precio FLOAT,
    stock INT,
    caducidad BOOLEAN,
    cod_prov VARCHAR(4),
    observaciones VARCHAR(45)
);
```

## Datos de articulos

```
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES('DR-001','Lejia',0.80,18,FALSE,'A002','Muy Toxica'),
                            ('DR-002','Suavizante',2.40,10,FALSE,'A001','No volcar'),
                            ('DR-003','Quitamancha',5.00,18,FALSE,'B001','Muy Toxico'),
                            ('PA-001','Pan',1.00,35,TRUE,'B001','No tocar con las manos'),
                            ('PA-002','Palmerita',2.10,8,TRUE,'A001','Aplicar max 5 paquetes'),
                            ('PA-003','Napolitana',1.00,44,TRUE,'A002','Chocolate crema'),
                            ('VE-001','Lechuga',1.50,27,TRUE,'B002','No meter en la nevera'),
                            ('VE-002','Zanahoria',3.00,330,TRUE,'A001','No meter en la nevera');
```

## Tabla cliente

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    cod_cliente INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dni VARCHAR(9),
    nombreCli VARCHAR(25),
    ap1 VARCHAR(35),
    ap2 VARCHAR(35),
    descuento INT
);
```

## Datos de clientes

```
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(null,'45098765G','Juan','Perez','Soler',5),
                           (null,'33456739H','Antonio','Garcia','Toro',8),
                           (null,'23478962S','Ramon','Gonzalez','Tamudo',0),
                           (null,'45765432F','Jesus','Duarte','Fortes',4),
                           (null,'29876098G','Gabriel','Lopez','Vazquez',2);
```

## Tabla detallesFacturas

```
CREATE TABLE detallesFacturas(
    nFactura INT,
    cod_art VARCHAR(6),
    cantidad INT,
    desc_especial INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (nFactura,cod_art)
);
```

## Datos de detallesFacturas

```
INSERT INTO detallesFacturas VALUES(6,'DR-003',5,2),
                                   (6,'PA-002',2,6),
                                   (7,'DR-003',4,0),
                                   (7,'DR-002',2,2),
                                   (8,'VE-002',3,5),
                                   (8,'PA-001',7,5),
                                   (1,'DR-001',2,2),
                                   (1,'PA-002',5,0),
                                   (1,'DR-002',10,4),
                                   (1,'VE-001',3,0),
                                   (2,'DR-002',2,4),
                                   (2,'VE-002',3,5),
                                   (2,'PA-001',2,2),
                                   (3,'PA-002',4,4),
                                   (3,'VE-002',1,3),
                                   (3,'DR-001',3,2),
                                   (4,'PA-001',2,0),
                                   (4,'PA-002',3,5),
                                   (4,'VE-002',2,2),
                                   (5,'VE-001',4,6),
                                   (5,'PA-001',3,3);
```

## Tabla facturas

```
CREATE TABLE facturas(
    nFactura INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nCliente INT,
    fecha DATE,
    forma_pago VARCHAR(20)
);
```

## Datos de facturas

```
INSERT INTO facturas VALUES(null,3,'2007-10-10','Contado'),
                           (null,2,'2007-10-11','Contado'),
                           (null,5,'2007-10-11','Cheque'),
                           (null,1,'2007-10-12','Transferencia'),
                           (null,5,'2007-10-14','Contado'),
                           (null,1,'2007-10-16','Cheque'),
                           (null,2,'2007-10-16','Transferencia'),
                           (null,4,'2007-10-17','Contado');
```

## Tabla proveedores

```
CREATE TABLE proveedores(
    cod_prov VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_prov VARCHAR(30),
    telefono VARCHAR(9),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    descuento_1 INT,
    descuento_2 INT
);
```

## Datos de proveedores

```
INSERT INTO proveedores VALUES('A001','Distribuciones Sur','956525354','Ceuta',5,10),
                              ('A002','Todomasa SL','952875309','Malaga',3,6),
                              ('A003','La mancha pastelera','953709912','Jaen',15,20),
                              ('B001','Romelsa','912345762','Madrid',10,20),
                              ('B002','Gegatur SL','933988344','Barcelona',7,13);
```

Os dejo la función que me falla también.

```
# Hacer una funcion que reciba el numero de una factura y devuelva el importe de esta

USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS codArt $$
CREATE FUNCTION codArt(codart VARCHAR(6))
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE codA FLOAT;
    DECLARE m INT;
    DECLARE aux FLOAT;
    SELECT articulos.precio,detallesFacturas.cantidad INTO codA,m FROM articulos,detallesFacturas WHERE detallesFacturas.cod_art=articulos.cod_art AND articulos.cod_art=codart;
    SET aux = codA*m;
    RETURN aux;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Lo que estoy intentado es multiplicar la **cantidad de detallesFacturas** con el **precio del articulos**.

**Os dejo un enlace del funcionamiento de la funcion :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/69

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar mi fallo, resulta que me faltaba el el **SELECT** sumar con la funcion **SUM()** la cantidad, eso es lo que me fallaba

```
# Hacer una funcion que reciba el numero de una factura y devuelva el importe de esta

USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS codArt $$
CREATE FUNCTION codArt(codart VARCHAR(6))
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE codA FLOAT;
    DECLARE m INT;
    SELECT articulos.precio,SUM(detallesFacturas.cantidad) INTO codA,m FROM articulos,detallesFacturas WHERE detallesFacturas.cod_art=articulos.cod_art AND articulos.cod_art=codart;
    RETURN codA*m;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Os dejo un enlace de como funciona :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/70